# Magento - How Are Promotion Actions Called To The Quote Object

Tags: php, magento

I would like to be able to create my own custom promotion action. There is very little documentation on the subject.

I am piecing some of it together by looking within `app/code/mage/SalesRule/`

However i thought that within the observer of this module there would be a method called at the cart to recalculate the total. The method that I see is `addProductAttributes`.

When I did a var dump of this, I had expected to see price somewhere in the mix, that is not the case.

How do sales rules affect the total cost? could someone point me in the right direction please.

-- Update : `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php` seems to be a key component (see `public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It starts on the Discount collector `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount`, it creates an instance of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` and loops through the quote to send the `$item` (or the child item, in case it's configurable) to the process method (line 99)

```
$this->_calculator->process($child);
```

In there it loops through the rules

```
foreach ($this->_getRules() as $rule)
```

Then you have two validations:

```
if (!$this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
    continue;
}

if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
   continue;
}
```

The first one checks the conditions, the second one, gets the condition action model, and sends the action to validate.

Then, depending on

```
$rule->getSimpleAction()
```

It decides what to do to the item.

Comment: Will play around with this and see if I can extend the functionality. Thank you.